# generate 30 random numbers between 1 and 10 using php

Tags: php

```
function randomNumbers ($start,$end,$quantity){
         $numbers = range($start, $end);
         shuffle($numbers);

         return array_slice($numbers,0,$quantity);
     }         
     $array=(randomNumbers(1,10,30));//calling a function
     print_r($array);// printing the output
```

The problem is that I am only getting 10 numbers not 30 as I want.

Comment: Well your basically trying to get 30 elements from an array with 10 elements. So you probably don't want to use `array_splice()` and instead `array_rand()` or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting only 10 numbers with this line

```
$numbers = range($start, $end);  // Get 1..10 range
```

so array_slice can get only 10 numbers. You can try with someting like this (maybe it is not the best code, but can help you)

```
function randomNumbers ($start,$end,$quantity){
    $numbers = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<$quantity/($end-$start); $i++)
        $numbers = array_merge($numbers, range($start, $end));
    shuffle($numbers);

    return array_slice($numbers,0,$quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way to generate 30 random number within a range of 1 to 10

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < 30; $i++){
 $num[$i] = rand(0,10);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($num);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_map(fn($e)=>rand(1,10), range(1,30))
```